# Getting attribute from overlapping feature from other polygon data using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, attribute-table, geoprocessing

How do I transfer attribute data from one polygon layer (A) to another (B)?

I am using ArcMap 10.2.

I tried using Identity. It doesn't work.

I also tried converting (A) to point so it has the same attribute. And every polygon of (B) has a point that derived from (A). I just don't know how to copy the point attribute to (B). 
By the way, (A) and (B) has no join key.

Comment: Try intersect and have a good look at output table. Join result to B table, using it's ID.

Comment: If your problem concerns no more than a few dozens, you could try using the "Attribute Transfer" command. You can drag and drop it from the Customize >>> Customize Mode >>> Commands

Answer (score 3):

Try **Spatial Join Tool**, set your **Target features** and **Join features** select the **Match Options** (the criteria of the join), set output feature class and fields that you want to transfer, set radius if required.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that this will not transfer the data from one layer to another, but will instead create a third layer (which is probably fine).   If you really did want the data transferred to the original layer (or feature class), then there would be some additional steps required.